# How to check whether we should go to google search or just simple load url

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am new to Android. I got stuck in such a small problem. I have edittext in my fragment. I want whatever user enter in edittext it should search on google. But whenever he enters any url then just simply load url in webview. I don't know how to check whether edittext contains url or not.

Here is my code, but it is not working:

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("searchvalue");
        if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(value) && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(value).matches()){
            url = value;
        }else {
            url = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/#q=" +
                    value).toString();
        }
```

This code is not working. It is everytime searching on google whether i am entering url or any random value.
Please help me.

Comment: The code you written is perfect ... i.e if the user enters valid url say www.example.com then if you open it will go to that website and if not it will search for the term in google what is that making you confuse ?

Comment: I think if you want to get the text inside of the editText then use this String value=editText.getText().toString(); it will give you the data entered in the editText... make sure you assign editText

Comment: Yeah i am getting the value of text inside of ediTtext, i am passing it through the intent and receiving  here with getIntent().

Comment: But code is not working. It is always searching on google whether it is any url or text.

Comment: Which url you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks really good. Perhaps the only missing thing is to include domains in addition to URLs. Just try appending HTTP:// in front of the value, something like this:

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("searchvalue");
        if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(value) && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(value).matches()){
            url = value;
        }
        else if(URLUtil.isValidUrl("http://" + value) && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher("http://" + value).matches()){
            url = "http://" + value;
        }
else {
            url = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/#q=" +
                    value).toString();
        }
```